# Django: Removing items from a QuerySet without affecting added fields

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-queryset

I've got a view handler in which I need to fetch a page of results for a particular query. However, after fetching the results I'd like to add a field to the objects and remove certain objects depending on the contents of that field. Something like this:

```
objResultSet = MyModel.objects.filter(some_filter_conditions)

lstToRemove = []
for objResult in objResultSet:
    objResult.extra_field = get_extra_field_contents(objResult)
    if should_remove_because_of_field(objResult.extra_field):
        lstToRemove.append(objResult.id)

objResultSet = objResultSet.exclude(id__in=lstToRemove)
objPage = get_page(objResultSet, RESULTS_PER_PAGE, iPageNum)
objResultSet = objPage.object_list

for objResult in objResultSet:
    do_something_with_extra_field(objResult.extra_field)
```

It appears that the line in which I exclude the IDs I've picked out strips off the extra field I've added, as if these results are coming straight from the database. Is there a way I can maintain these extra fields I've added while still removing certain items from the QuerySet?

Answer (score 1):

[Querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), when iterating on `objResultSet` you're evaluating the queryset and iterating through the results by creating MyModel instances. You're adding extra fields to those model instances.

However you're using the *original* queryset to exclude the specific IDs, which causes a new evaluation of the queryset which creates new model instances without the extra fields.

Try creating a list of the model instances with the extra fields and working with those instead of reusing the queryset. Something like this:

```
objResultSet = MyModel.objects.filter(some_filter_conditions)

extra_fields_models = []
for objResult in objResultSet:
    objResult.extra_field = get_extra_field_contents(objResult)
    if not should_remove_because_of_field(objResult.extra_field):
        extra_fields_models.append(objResult)

objPage = get_page(extra_fields_models, RESULTS_PER_PAGE, iPageNum)
for objResult in extra_fields_models:
    do_something_with_extra_field(objResult.extra_field)
```